# Angular 2, RC6 - Referencing an HTML element without @ViewChild

Tags: angular, angular-template

Using Angular 2, RC6, I need to need to create a function that references the element in the template from which it fires. For example, if I have a `<div>` and click on it, the attached function would tell me about the `<div>`.

Here is a "broken" example (pseudo-code):

```
@Component({
    selector: 'example',
    template: `
        <div id="example" (click)="myExampleFunction(this, $event)">
            Some text
        </div>
    `
})
export class ExampleComponent {
    public myExampleFunction(el: Element, ev: Event): void {
        console.info('Element', el);
        console.info('Event', ev);
    }
}
```

This example will not work because the `this` parameter returns the entire `ExampleComponent` instead of just the `<div>`. The `$event` parameter works as expected, though.

Angular has introduced the concept of `@ViewChild`, which may work here. However, I would really prefer to keep the process simple and not have extraneous code. All I need is the referenced element. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use

```
<div id="example" #example (click)="myExampleFunction(example, $event)">
```

or

```
<div id="example" (click)="myExampleFunction($event)">
```

```
export class ExampleComponent {
    public myExampleFunction(ev: Event): void {
        console.info('Element', ev.target);
        console.info('Event', ev);
    }
}
```

Comment: `<div id="example" (click)="myExampleFunction($event)">` with `ev.target` works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may look into `$event` for `srcElement`  which gives the div you are looking for.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>
   <div id="example" (click)="myExampleFunction($event)">
            Some text
        </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent { 

  public myExampleFunction(ev: Event): void {
       console.log(ev);
       console.info('Event', ev.srcElement);
    }
}

// Result
    <div id="example">
                Some text
            </div>
```

Here is [PLunker!!](http://plnkr.co/edit/H7cP9fzlht8PLd04XlyX?p=preview)

Hope this helps!!

Comment: When I run your code `console.info('Event', ev.srcElement);`displays `undefined`

Comment: Did you check the Plunker?

Comment: Yes, but don't worry about it. Using `ev.target` returns the referenced element.